# GDI+ Nested Graphics objects

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

With `System.Drawing.Graphics`, how can I have "nested graphics objects". 
The main purpose is to have several clipped regions.

This is somehow the thing I want to do:

[image]

The whole screen is a Graphics object

Red area is another Graphics inside it and clipped

Green area is another one, clipped

Inside Graphics objects can be anything NOT only `DrawString`

The code should look like this:

```
using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(200, 200))
using (var mainG = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
using (var redG = ???)
using (var greenG = ???)
{
    redG.SetClip(new RectangleF(...));
    greenG.SetClip(new RectangleF(...));

    // fill redG and greenG
}
```

NOTE: the result should go to a meta file and be vector graphic, so creating *bitmaps* and placing them around the mainG is NOT an option.

Comment: Wouldn't using `mainG.SetClip(boundsOfRedArea)` work for you? You can then draw on `mainG` as if it was a separate `redG` graphics object.

Comment: then how to clip the green area?

Comment: After you're done drawing red, you simply `SetClip` to green's area.

Comment: The question is general. It might be more than two areas and there might be areas inside areas

Comment: besides you cannot have more than one clip

Comment: You cannot have more than one clip _at a time_, that much is true. I didn't post this as answer because I was unsure if it would solve your problem, and I still am

Comment: If bitmaps won't work, then create a vector graphics image (such as EMF) and draw into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's okay for the two vector contexts to be seperate while they are drawn into, you can use System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile to catch the vector operations and then combine them into the bigger context.. Something like this:

```
using (Graphics gRef = this.CreateGraphics())  
{  
    IntPtr hdc = gRef.GetHdc();  
    using (System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile mf = 
           new System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile(hdc, 
                System.Drawing.Imaging.EmfType.EmfPlusDual))  
        {  
          gRef.ReleaseHdc();  

          using (Graphics redG = Graphics.FromImage(mf))  
          {  
            redG.SetClip(new RectangleF(...));

            // .. draw on redG 
          }  
          // repeat for greenG

          // .. save and or combine as desired

        }  
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to study the Enhanced Metafile format (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230724.aspx) and try to reproduce clipping masks manually.

Comment: Exactly! this question came to my mind after studying that format and I was wondering how is that possible to reproduce clippings that are available there in GDI+ :)

Comment: Well I guess now you know the answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find GDI+ equivalences